# VB6 exe errors - run time errors

Tags: dll, vb6, exe

I was wondering if somebody could help me here.

I'm looking after some legacy code written in VB6. I made some updates to this code, just to remove some redundant pieces. I tested this on my development machine before making an exe - it ran fine, no problems (happy days).

I created an exe on the same machine and I am now getting the following errors when I click on  2 of 2 command buttons:

**1. Run time error '53' - File not found**      --- this message appears without a dll reference.

**2. Run tim error '91'**  - Object variable or with block variable not set.

---

So, since the code ran fine before the exe was created, would you say this is an environment problem - dll's missing, etc... 
I'm assuming exe's require different references to do the same job as the application before it is made into an exe.

I'm a novice when it comes to VB6 and I'm not really too sure about what's going on under the hood when these errors pop up.

Thanks.

Comment: I solved the run time error '53' problem anyway - the version of Excel on the test environment (called by the application) was never right - sooo, problem moved :)

Comment: Error 91 means that your program is trying to use an object because it has been set to a valid reference either by setting it using the New statement or by setting it to an existing variable that has a valid reference to an object.
Do you happen to have any code?